# Can't get rid of a flash of content from after ajax page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page that makes different ajax calls based on what element one clicks on. There are four IDs and only one should be visible at any given moment. My problem comes when I load new ajax content into a div - I get a flash for a very brief second of the previous content. Here is one of my functions for one of the calls (they are all essentially the same). At the beginning of the function I hide everything. Then after the ajax has loaded I show the relevant div. I'm confused about why this would not work. There should be no flash, since all the div are hidden, right?

```
            $('body').on("click", "#answer-submit", function() {

                $('#games, #location, #question, #answer').css('display' , 'none');

                var theAnswer = $('#challenge-answer').val();
                   $.ajax({ 
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax/answer.php",
                        data: { answer : theAnswer },
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function(msg){
                                    if(parseInt(msg)!=0) {
                                        $('#answer').html(msg);
                                    }
                                }
                    }); 
                    $('#answer').css('display' , 'block');
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is an asynchronous request is going to happen asynchronously. In other words, your success function is going to be called after `$('#answer').css('display' , 'block');` (it is a race condition but it's practically guaranteed). The solution is simple -- move `$('#answer').css('display' , 'block');` into the `success` function:

```
        $('body').on("click", "#answer-submit", function() {

            $('#games, #location, #question, #answer').css('display' , 'none');

            var theAnswer = $('#challenge-answer').val();
               $.ajax({ 
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/answer.php",
                    data: { answer : theAnswer },
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(msg){
                                if(parseInt(msg)!=0) {
                                    $('#answer').html(msg);
                                    $('#answer').css('display' , 'block');
                                }
                            }
                }); 

        });
```

You can even chain it like so:

```
if (parseInt(msg) != 0) {
  $('#answer')
    .html(msg)
    .css('display', 'block');
}
```

Comment: Nice. Asynchronous! Thank you.